# java.lang.AssertionError when executing unit test when using my own model as parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, assertion

I got a AssertionError when I execute the unit test. response.getBody() is null.

Here is unit test method;

```
public void when_CustomerNumNotNull_Expect_TspResult() {
   /*
     some code
   */

    TspResultDto tspResultDto = new TspResultDto();

    tspResultDto.setTspResult("blabla");

    Mockito.doReturn(tspResultDto).when(creditService)
        .getTspResult(tspInputDto);

    ResponseEntity<TspResponse> response = creditController
        .getTspResult(TspRequest);

    Assert.assertNotNull(response.getBody()); // error occured this line because body null.
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
    //Assert.assertEquals(true, response.getBody().isHrResult());
  }

    }
```

TspInputDto and TspRequest are my model Class.
But I don't get an error when I run it with a single parameter like below without needing the model class.

```
Mockito.doReturn(newCreditApplicationDto).when(creditService)
        .getNewCreditApplicationNo(customerNum);

    ResponseEntity<NewCreditApplicationResponse> response = creditController
        .getNewCreditApplicationNo(customerNum);

    Assert.assertNotNull(response.getBody());
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
```

Here is controller;

```
public ResponseEntity<TspResponse> getTspResult(
      TspRequest tspRequest) {

    TspInputDto tspInputDto = creditDemandRestMapper
        .toTspInputDto(tspRequest);

    TspResultDto tspResultDto = creditService
        .getTspResult(tspInputDto);

    TspResponse tspResponse = creditDemandRestMapper
        .toTspResponse(tspResultDto);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(tspResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

  }
```

Here is service;

```
public TspResultDto getTspResult(
      TspInputDto tspInputDto) {

    TspResultDto tspResultDto = new TspResultDto();

    /*
       Some code here...
    */
    return tspResultDto;
  }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question is little unclear, please provide more details regarding CreditController and CreditService. Also in creditController, you are passing TspRequest.

Comment: Service and Controller  added to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
Mockito.doReturn(tspResultDto).when(creditService)
        .getTspResult(tspInputDto);
```

you set the mock to return your `tspResultDto` object if the argument `equals()` to `tspInputDto`, meaning it should be an equal object (in terms of `equals()` comparison). Probably your `TspInputDto` class doesn't have `equals` method defined properly.

Anyways, I'd propose to rewrite this line of code using `argThat` matcher:

```
Mockito.doReturn(tspResultDto).when(creditService)
        .getTspResult(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(tspInputDto ->
            // condition for provided tspInputDto
        ));
```

Comment: If it has equals, correct me if am wrong, you would still need to not have a plain object, but rather want to use ArgumentMatchers#eq in mocked method  argument

Comment: I believe Mockito is smart enough to assume `eq()` if only one argument is present. It's when you have other arguments with different matchers, then Mockito would explicitly complain, and you'd need to specify the `eq()` matcher explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mocked the creditController? If you haven't then it will not give you response mock object.